# Wireless icon missing in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, icons, system-tray

My system is running on 12.04.4, 64 bit and the wireless icon is missing. There are no connectivity issues, but it becomes tedious to choose a different network from the Network menu than the tray.

Answer (score 0):

Press Function key + F2. It shows wifi icon

Comment: thank you for answering, I tried it but it didn't work.